# Reset(TextInput) on Button click Error "The function expects a resettable control as its input"

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerquery, powerapps, power-automate

I want to reset "Text" property of TextInput using *Reset(TextInput);* function

Initially I set the "Text" property to a variable then using

Below function on button *OnSelect*

```
UpdateContext({coordinates:Location.Latitude & ","& Location.Longitude});Reset(textInput)
```

*Reset()* function gives following error **"The function expects a resettable control as its input."**

Where is it wrong?

Comment: Is your text input inside a form or gallery?

Answer (score 1):

Likely your input is inside a gallery or form. You'll have to include your reset button in the same gallery or form as your input.

[image]